# failed to load external entity xml file

Tags: xml, libxml2

I am parsing xml file by using libxml2.0, the code is below here.

I am getting error as Failed to load external entity.

```
xmlDocPtr xmlDocumentPtr = xmlParseFile(inXMLFilePath.c_str());
```

I am getting null for the pointer xmlDocPtr xmlDocumentPtr;

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the XML have a DTD? The DTD could be embedded or included by reference to a URI. The error implies that the DTD has an external entity and libxml2 could not find the definition for it. Check the DTD for `<!ENTITY entity_name ...>`. The entity declaration may refer to a URI that could not be found.

Another possiblity is that the XML references a entity without a declaration in any DTD e.g. `&entity_name;` appears in the XML but there is no corresponding `<!ENTITY entity_name ...>` declaration.

Also the error message should have had the name of the entity or the URI of the DTD after it. Did it?

Comment: Now it is fixed. just missed file path.